# Rails / Postgres aggregating column values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a rails model called `TopicSubscription` which has 2 main columns.

- user_id (integer)
- topic_id (integer)

I'm trying to write a query that will return a hash like this:

```
{user_id1 => [topic_ids], user_id2 => [topic_ids] }
```

Where the keys are user_ids and and the values are arrays of topic_ids.

This is the query that I've tried:

```
TopicSubscription.select("ARRAY_AGG(topic_id) AS topic_ids, user_id").where(topic_id: [1,2,3].group(:user_id)
```

However it returns something like this:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<TopicSubscription id: nil, user_id: 1>, #<TopicSubscription id: nil, user_id: 2>]>
```

I am using Rails 4.2 and Postgres 9.4. I'm trying to avoid using Enumerable#group_by as in production its going to be selecting thousands / tens of thousands of rows.

What is the correct way to write this query to get the data in the format that I'm looking for?

Comment: Have you called `topic_ids` on the returned objects?

Comment: Aha that worked, Thanks for the help :)